# Arabic Memoir Book Fine Tuning

Tags: memoir, books

How can I fine-tune this memoir code.
I would like to do the following which is shown in the attached images.

```
 \documentclass[11pt,openany]{memoir}


  \usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{fancybox}
  \usepackage{geometry}
  \usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
  \usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics
  \usepackage{framed}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
  \usepackage{mdframed}   
  \usepackage{longtable}
  \usepackage{mathtools}
  \usepackage{glossaries}
  \usepackage{makeidx}
  \usepackage{hyphenat}       % I use it to prevent hyphenation of table of contents items
  %\usepackage{avant} % Use the Avantgarde font for headings
  \usepackage{mathptmx}
  \usepackage{microtype} % Slightly tweak font spacing for aesthetics
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for including letters with accents
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Use 8-bit encoding that has 256 glyphs
  \usepackage{smartdiagram}
  \usesmartdiagramlibrary{additions}
  \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
  \usepackage{cleveref}
  \tcbuselibrary{skins}
  \RequirePackage{amsthm}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows}

  \usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
  \tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
  \colorlet{MainGrey}{white!50!black}
  \newcommand{\OwnerOne}{\textarabic{الكاتب المخضرم}


  \geometry{ 
paperwidth=6.125in, 
paperheight=9.25in,
top=0.75in, % Top margin
bottom=0.75in, % Bottom margin
left=0.75in, % Left margin
right=0.5in, % Right margin
inner=0.75in,
outer=0.5in,
headheight=14pt, % Header height
footskip=0.35in, % Space from the bottom margin to the baseline of the footer
headsep=0.35in, % Space from the top margin to the baseline of the header
twoside,
bindingoffset=0.13in
%showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
  }

  \newcommand{\RedBarLength}{3em}

  \newsavebox{\ChpNumBox}
  \newsavebox{\ChpContBox}

  \makeatletter
  \newcommand*{\thickhrulefill}{%
    \leavevmode\leaders\hrule height 3\p@ \hfill \kern \z@}
  \newcommand*\BuildChpNum[3]{%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
    \makebox[0pt][c]{#1\strut} \\[.5ex]
    \colorbox{MainGrey}{%
        \rule[-\RedBarLength-(#3)]{0pt}{0pt}%
        \rule{1ex}{0pt}\color{white}#2\strut
        \rule{.8ex}{0pt}}%
  \end{tabular}}
  \makechapterstyle{BoxedChapNum}{%
\renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\large\scshape}
\setlength{\beforechapskip}{-30pt}
\setlength{\midchapskip}{10pt}
\setlength{\afterchapskip}{30pt}
\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{}
\renewcommand{\printchapternum}{%
    %       \startcontents[chapters]
    %       \sbox{\ChpContBox}{%
    %           \parbox{\linewidth}{%
    %               \printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{\color{blue}}%
    %       }}%
    \sbox{\ChpNumBox}{%
        \BuildChpNum{\color{black}\bfseries\chapnamefont\@chapapp}%
        {\chapnumfont\HUGE\thechapter}%
        {\ht\ChpContBox+\dp\ChpContBox}%
}}
%   \renewcommand{\printchapternonum}{%
%       \startcontents[chapters]
%       \sbox{\ChpContBox}{%
%           \parbox{\linewidth}{%
%%              \printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}%  Useless?
%       }}%
%       \sbox{\ChpNumBox}{%
%           \BuildChpNum{\chapnamefont\vphantom{\@chapapp}}%
%           {\chapnumfont\hphantom{\thechapter}}%
%           {\ht\ChpContBox+\dp\ChpContBox}%
%   }}
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}
\renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
    \usebox{\ChpNumBox}\hfill
    \parbox[t]{\hsize-\wd\ChpNumBox-1em}{%
        \raggedleft\vspace{\midchapskip}%
        {\color{MainGrey}\thickhrulefill}\\[10pt]
        {\chaptitlefont\LARGE\textcolor{black}{\nohyphens{##1}}}\par\vspace*{10pt}
        \renewcommand\cftsectionpagefont{\itshape\color{black}}
        \renewcommand\cftsubsectionpagefont{\itshape\color{black}}
        \renewcommand\cftsectionfont{\color{black}}
        \renewcommand\cftsubsectionfont{\color{black}}
        %           \printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}%
}}%
} 


  % ---------------- Styling parts ------------------
  \renewcommand{\partnamefont}{\HUGE\scshape\centering\MakeLowercase}
  \renewcommand{\partnumfont}{\HUGE\scshape\centering\MakeLowercase}
  \renewcommand{\printparttitle}{\HUGE\scshape\centering\MakeLowercase}
  \renewcommand{\printpartname}{\HUGE\color{black}}
  \makeatother 


  \renewenvironment{leftbar}{%
    \def\FrameCommand{\textcolor{black}{\vrule width 2pt depth 6pt}\hspace*{15pt}}%
      \MakeFramed{\advance\hsize-\width\FrameRestore}}%
  {\endMakeFramed}

  % a command to circle the part numbers
  \newcommand\Circle[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] 
    \node[draw=black, circle, text width=18pt,line width=1pt,align=center] {#1};}

  % redefinition of the name of the ToC
  \renewcommand\printtoctitle[1]{\HUGE\bfseries#1}

  \makeatletter

  % redefinitions for part entries
  \renewcommand\cftpartfont{\huge\bfseries\hfill}
  \renewcommand\partnumberline[1]{%
\hbox to \textwidth{\hss\Circle{\textcolor{black}{#1}}\hss}%
\vskip3.5ex\par\hfill\color{black}}
\renewcommand*\cftpartformatpnum[1]{\hfill}
\renewcommand\cftpartafterpnum{\vskip1ex}

% redefinitions for chapter entries
\renewcommand\chapternumberline[1]{\raggedleft\mbox{\LARGE\@chapapp~#1}\par\noindent\Large}
%\renewcommand\chapternumberline{\Large}
\renewcommand\cftchapterfont{}
\cftsetindents{chapter}{0pt}{0em}
\renewcommand\cftchapterpagefont{\Huge\bfseries\color{black}}

\newcommand*{\l@mychap}[3]{%
\def\@chapapp{\color{black}#3}
\vskip1ex%
\par\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
    \parbox{4.5em}{%
        \hfill{\cftchapterpagefont#2}%
    }\hspace*{1.5em}%
    \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-4.5em-15pt\relax}{%
        \leftbar\cftchapterfont{\color{black}#1}\hspace{1sp}\endleftbar%
    }%
\end{minipage}\par%
}
 \renewcommand*{\l@chapter}[2]{%
     \l@mychap{#1}{#2}{\chaptername}%
}
 \renewcommand*{\l@appendix}[2]{%
    \l@mychap{#1}{#2}{\appendixname}%
}


% redefinitions for section entries
\renewcommand\cftsectionfont{\color{black}}
\renewcommand\cftsectionpagefont{\itshape\color{black}}
\renewcommand\cftsectionleader{\nobreak}
\renewcommand\cftsectiondotsep{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand\cftsectionafterpnum{\hspace*{\fill}}
\setlength\cftsectionnumwidth{12em}
\cftsetindents{section}{6em}{3em}
\renewcommand\cftsectionformatpnum[1]{%
\hskip1em\hbox to \@pnumwidth{{\cftsectionpagefont #1\hfill}}}


% redefinitions for subsection entries


\renewcommand\cftsubsectionfont{\color{black}}
\renewcommand\cftsubsectionpagefont{\itshape\color{MainRed}}
\renewcommand\cftsubsectionleader{\nobreak}
\renewcommand\cftsubsectiondotsep{\cftnodots}
\renewcommand\cftsubsectionafterpnum{\hspace*{\fill}}
\setlength\cftsubsectionnumwidth{12em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{9em}{3em}
\renewcommand\cftsubsectionformatpnum[1]{%
\hskip1em\hbox to \@pnumwidth{{\cftsubsectionpagefont #1\hfill}}}


\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}


\makeatother


%%%% End of Pretty ToC



%%%%%% use the newly defined style

\chapterstyle{BoxedChapNum}
\settocdepth{subsection}
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Mapping=arabicdigits]{Amiri}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setdefaultlanguage{arabic}
\setRTL

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\thispagestyle{empty} % Suppress headers and footers on the title page
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw (current page.center) [anchor=north] node [fill=white,fill opacity=0.6,text opacity=1,inner sep=1cm]{\Huge\centering\bfseries\parbox[c][][t]{\paperwidth}{\centering التجربة\\[15pt] % Book title
{\Large \textarabic{أول كتاب شامل في  الدول العالمية}}\\[20pt] % Subtitle
{\LARGE \OwnerOne \\ }}}; % Author name
\end{tikzpicture}
\vfill
\endgroup


\nouppercaseheads
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents*

\newpage
\listoffigures

\newpage
\listoftables

\mainmatter

\part{بارت}
\chapter{السيارة }
\chapter{الطيارة}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a partial answer.

*Error* Your sample code contains an error. Add a closing brace.

```
\newcommand{\OwnerOne}{\textarabic{الكاتب المخضرم}}% <<< Closing brace added
```

*Changing the chapter name.* Before `\begin{document}`, add the following lines.

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\captionsarabic
  {\chaptername{\@ensure@RTL{باب}}}% text to replace
  {\chaptername{\@ensure@RTL{فَصْل}}}% replacement text
  {}{}
\makeatother
```

This will affect the table of contents as well as the chapter headers as well.

*Making it larger* Check you log file. I get several warnings regarding fonts that are not available and therefore are substituted. This may lead to text that is typeset in a smaller or lighter font than intended.

Comment: It is not working. I have added xpatch code but nothing has changed.

Comment: @OOzyPal If you take your code, correct the error, add my code verbatim directly before `\begin{document}`, and it doesn't work, then you maybe have an older version of `polyglossia`. Either upgrade, or search for the code yourself. In `gloss-arabic.ldf`, I have a command `\captionsarabic`, which sets `\chaptername` using the sequence in my `\xpatchcmd` call ('text to replace').